# when refreshing data from my table database. "Check the manual that corresponds to mysql version for the right syntax to use"

Tags: java, mysql-workbench

```
try
{
    ConMySqlConnectionString = DriverManager.getConnection(strDBConnectionString,strDBUser,strDBPassword);

    StStatement = conMySqlConnectionString.createStatement();

    String strQuery ="select first_name, last_name, job_tittle, department, date_of_birth, phone_number from employee_information" ;

    StStatement.execute(strQuery);
    rs=stStatement.getResultSet();
}
```

Comment: first thing, did you "Check the manual that corresponds to mysql version for the right syntax to use” ?

Comment: usual it tells you location of syntax error.. anyways check names are correct